# Datastax Cassandra .NET Client Linq Datacontext

Tags: c#, linq, cassandra, crud

I can't find any Linq to Cassandra CQL sample online. Anybody can write simple program about these:

1-How to Create Datacontext.

2-How to Use CRUD with linq.

Comment: The library I use is [http://fluentcassandra.com/](http://fluentcassandra.com/) there are examples on the site

Answer (score 0):

The CassandraCSharpDriver from nugget has comprehensive documentation on this. The driver comes with 4 componenents.

1. CORE
2. MAPPER
3. LINQ
4. ADO.NET

For the LINQ component, the documentation can be found at [LINQ DRIVER DOCUMENTATION](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/2.5/csharp-driver/reference/linqComponent.html)
I hope you find this helpful.